# How to remove all Int values from Dictionary?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
var dictionary: [String: Any] = ["test1": "one", "test2": "two", "test3": 3, "test4": 4]
```

What is the best way to get a new dictionary, but only with String values?

Comment: This is pretty suspect. How did you end up with a dictionary of both ints and strings?

Comment: Trying to understand, or perhaps this approach may be useful. Actually work with an array that has data of different types.

Comment: For one, this is a dictionary, not an array. And also, having a dict value type that's completely unconstrained (`Any` type) is ***rarely*** what people actually need. It indicates that either the entire dict should be a model object (an instance of a struct or a class), or that the value should instead be bounded to some protocol or enumeration type. It's very rare that people say `Any` to the type system, but can *actually* handle *any* type.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong, it's really dictionary. In a particular case, I specified the type Any. But at the same time, 2 types are used here: Int, String, which can be added to the protocol as you specified. Thank you  for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write an extension for Dictionary:

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value: Any {
    var withoutInt: [String: Any] {
        return self.filter{ $0.value is String }
    }
}
```

And then use it:

```
dictionary = dictionary.withoutInt
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
for (key, value) in dictionary {

   if let value = value as? Int {
      dictionary.removeValue(forKey: key)
   }
}
```

Pseudo steps:

1.) Check each key/value pair in the dictionary

2.) Check if the value is an Integer

3.) If value is an integer, remove dictionary value associated with that key for that pair

Caveat: This is modifying your original dictionary. If you wanted to create a new (second instance) of your dictionary and keep the original intact, I think this would be as simple as creating a new dictionary and assigning it to the values of the original, then modifying the second dictionary instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can just filter those that are numbers.

Get those that are strings.

```
dictionary = dictionary.filter({ ($0.value as? Int) == nil })
```

Get those that are Ints

```
dictionary = dictionary.filter({ ($0.value as? Int) != nil })
```

All we do here are filter by cast typing to Int and seeing if it is `nil` or not.

Note: Could just do to original dictionary --

```
var dictionary: [String: Any] = ["test1": "one", "test2": "two", "test3": 3, "test4": 4].filter({ ($0.value as? Int) == nil })
```

OR

```
var dictionary: [String: Any] = ["test1": "one", "test2": "two", "test3": 3, "test4": 4].filter({ ($0.value as? Int) != nil })
```

Comment: Note that the result here would be an array of tuples, not a `Dictionary`

Comment: Erm, are ya sure? I can do `print(dictionary["test1"])` and it returns `("one")`

Comment: Oops... my mistake, seems this changed in Swift 4, before that `filter` would've give you an array of tuples.

Comment: ;) all good. I wouldn't have provided this filter if it worked that way haha. This is just the simplest in my mind. `Filter` defines his exact problem.

Comment: This is an incorrect question. `($0.value as? Int) == nil ` doesn't guarantee that the result will be String. And more swift-like is using 'is' instead.

Comment: 1) This is an answer; not a question. 2) The question says he wants to remove all `Int` values and return only string. That question implies to me that the dictionary **ONLY** contains `String` and `Int` types but to dictate that we use `[String : Any]`. 3) This guarantees it won't be an `Int` which is the headline of the question: "How to remove all Int values from Dictionary?". So I answered the question. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (key, value) in dictionary {
    if let v = value as? Int {
        dictionary.removeValue(forKey : key)
    }
}
```

if you don't modify parent dictionary then

```
func removeInt(dictionary : [String : Any]) ->[String : Any] {
    var dict2 = NSMutableDictionary() 
    for (key, value) in dictionary {
    if let v = value as? Int {
        dict2.setValue(v, forKey : key)
    }
  }
  return (dict2 as! [String : Any])
}
```